# Sending email through gmail using SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to send an email through following code

CODE

---

```
    Dim MyMailMessage As New MailMessage()
    'From requires an instance of the MailAddress type
    MyMailMessage.From = New MailAddress("a@gmail.com")
    'To is a collection of MailAddress types
    MyMailMessage.To.Add("a@something.com")
    MyMailMessage.Subject = "GMail Test"
    MyMailMessage.Body = "This is the test text for Gmail email"
    'Create the SMTPClient object and specify the SMTP GMail server
    Dim SMTPServer As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
    SMTPServer.Port = 465
    SMTPServer.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("a@gmail.com", "*****")
    SMTPServer.EnableSsl = True
    Try
        SMTPServer.Send(MyMailMessage)
        MessageBox.Show("Email Sent")
    Catch ex As SmtpException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

---

However this code is not working
I get following exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in MailSender.exe
```

And finally delivery of message fails.

Any idea why it is not working?

NOTE : I have tried  SMTPServer.Port = 587 too but still its not working

Comment: Have a look at the inner exception - tell us what it is.

Comment: What exception are you getting? What's in your MessageBox?

Comment: Following are the exceptions i could see in output: 1) A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' occurred in System.dll 2) A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll 3) A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occurred in System.dll 4)  A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in System.dll 5) A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in MailSender.exe

Comment: @Tim My message box shows :

"Failure sending mail."

Comment: @Isentropic You need to run this in the Visual Studio debugger, and inspect `ex.InnerException` to find out the reason this is failing, or modify your code to print `ex.InnerException` (and `ex.InnerException.InnerException`, and so on)

Comment: @Tim inner exception is -
"Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: @Isentropic Sounds like you need to follow @Igal's advice - some setting on your network is stopping you from connecting to the Google server

Comment: Not only do you have a network problem, but you cannot relay mail through Gmail's SMTP servers!  They don't allow it.  You can only use their SMTP servers to deliver to Gmail addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to isolate port problem do the following test:
Start>run> type there "cmd"> enter.
in the black screen type: `telnet smtp.gmail.com 465`.

if you get this message:

```
Connecting To smtp.gmail.com...Could not open connection to the host, on port 465: Connect failed
```

it means you network administrator closed this port to outside connection.
If you get black empty screen it means the connection is OK.
if the command telnet is not available for you, you have to add this service (search Google how to add telnet client)

Comment: Thanks Igal. I tried it. I am getting 'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. I will add telnet service. & then wil tell u the result

Comment: OK, after you will check you will have a clear answer that is not generated threw exception.

Comment: yup i got the same message as u described.

Comment: If the network administrator will not open this port, try to check wich ports are open for outside connection. if the port 25 us open, you can use other smtp server that uses this port (usually this port is used by mail servers)